# how to install expo-cli offline in windows 10

Tags: react-native

```html
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.829]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\HPSupport>npm install -g expo-cli
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ because the host is inaccessible -- are you offline?
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.4.4: ?? As of Babel 7.4.0, this
npm WARN deprecated package has been deprecated in favor of directly
npm WARN deprecated including core-js/stable (to polyfill ECMAScript
npm WARN deprecated features) and regenerator-runtime/runtime
npm WARN deprecated (needed to use transpiled generator functions):
npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated   > import "core-js/stable";
npm WARN deprecated   > import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HPSupport\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-14T04_03_13_221Z-debug.log

C:\Users\HPSupport>
```

when I try to install expo cli with "npm install -g expo-cli"
Installing just stuck on something like "extracting rxjs"

Is there any way to install it offline with its offline installer
or any solution to this problem.

I am using the latest node version- v10

I have deleted node 64 bit and installed node 32 bit but the same problem,
I have the same issue when trying to use PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so after a bit of research and the error I got now it is clear that this is a problem from npm so I just installed react-native-cli instead of expo-cli and it worked.

thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
react-native init AwesomeApp
cd AwesomeApp
npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an npm error

Try use yarn.

```
yarn global add expo-cli
```

i faced this error and yarn solved it.

Also you can find many useful suggestions in this link
https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/590

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your internet connection? I had an issue relating to this sometimes back. All I did was to subscribe to faster internet and the installation was successful.

Comment: I have a good internet connection (4G), One thing that I know is that this is not an internet problem because of it just freezes and never move on the second line. Please help, is there any way to download it from any website with the browser and install it normally like any other windows software?

Comment: What version of Node are you on?

Comment: My Node version is 6.9.0 (32 bit), I have tried Node 6.9.0 (64 bit) but the problem continues.

Comment: when I try today to install expo cli again, this time I got an error on extracting rxjs line. I have added a log to my question.